# How do I use Schema.org to identify filters on our hotel search site?

Tags: html, filtering, schema.org, microdata

I'm working on a site designed to help a user find a hotel. We've got lots of widgets for filtering the hotels we show (e.g. price filters) or else ordering the hotels we show (e.g. by distance).

I can see how to markup our hotels as [being a list](https://schema.org/ItemList). And also how to communicate the [sort order](https://schema.org/itemListOrder) of the list.

And we're already marking up the hotel's themselves:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel">
    <div itemprop="image" style="background-image: url('{{{ imageUrl }}}');"></div>
    <h2 class="title" itemprop="name">{{ name }}</h2>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <div itemprop="price">{{{ price }}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way of identifying our filters as being tools for adjusting the list?

To get an idea of how the website works see - http://mapov.com/hotels/the+strip/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way of identifying our filters as being tools for adjusting the list?

With an [`Action`](http://schema.org/Action) type.

See [`SearchAction`](http://schema.org/SearchAction) or perhaps [`FindAction`](http://schema.org/FindAction) ([`DiscoverAction`](http://schema.org/DiscoverAction)).

An `Action` can be used to represent what happened (e.g., "User 3 searched for hotels in Amsterdam"), but also for representing potential actions: use the [`potentialAction`](http://schema.org/potentialAction) property to specify the possible actions an item can have.

```html
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
  <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
    …
  </div>
</section>
```

#### Side notes about your markup

- Your `image` property won’t work, it can’t have an image specified in the `style` attribute as value. You have to provide the `image` property on a "link" element (e.g., `img`, `a`, `link`, …).
- Your `Offer` is not associated with the `Hotel`. You could use the [`makesOffer`](http://schema.org/makesOffer) property.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel">
 <img itemprop="image" src="http://yourhostel.es/content/124"/>
 <meta itemprop="address" content="you street"/>
<h2 class="title" itemprop="name">name </h2>
<div itemprop="priceRange">price</div><div itemprop="telephone">9999999</div>
```

price